# How to write a Java web-service for which the generated WSDL has multiple bindings

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

How can I write a Java web-service using standard annotations which has a generated WSDL with multiple bindings (for example, for both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2)?